# 'rgl' translation issues in R

Tags: r, opengl, rgl

I've plotted up a series of points using the `rgl` package in R.  I've plotted them in two dimensions for simplicity, but the issue still exists in three dimensions.  The code snippet and plot below show a basic line of points plotted in the xy-plane:

```
library(rgl)
seq <- seq(1, 10, by = 0.1)
df <- data.frame(x = seq, y = seq / 10)

clear3d("all")
bg3d(color = "white")
points3d(x = df$x, y = df$y, z = 0)
axes3d()
rgl.viewpoint(theta = 0, phi = 0)
```

[image: First plot]

The points plot as expected.  However, if I take these same points and translate them by a significant amount, the graphics device does not seem to be able to handle the points:

```
library(rgl)
seq <- seq(1, 10, by = 0.1)
df <- data.frame(x = seq, y = seq / 10)

# Translate points
df <- df + 1000000

clear3d("all")
bg3d(color = "white")
points3d(x = df$x, y = df$y, z = 0)
axes3d()
rgl.viewpoint(theta = 0, phi = 0)
```

[image: Second plot]

Is this a known limitation?  Is the problem with OpenGL, or with the package?  I'm working with some points and surfaces that have an associated coordinate system, so I'd prefer not to translate my data back to the origin.

Comment: Looks to me like you are limited to floatting-point precision. OpenGL byu default only works with single precision floats (which is perfectly fine for graphics). With modern GL and GPUs (GL 4.x), you could really use double precision for the vertex data and transformation, but I don't know if rgl would support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@derhass had the right idea.  From the `rgl` manual:

> Note that many of these calculations are done on the graphics card using single precision; you will likely see signs of rounding error if your scene requires more than 4 or 5 digit precision to distinguish values in any coordinate.